# ¿Como seria la consulta correcta?

Tags: php, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT `movimientos`.`codigo_material`, if (`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento`='ENTRADA')
SUM(`movimientos`.`cantidad`)
WHERE 
`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento`;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientos` (
  `identrada` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `num_factura` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_material` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_movimiento` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `no_orden` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retira` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ubicacion_material` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(6,0) NOT NULL
```

Intento hacer una busqueda en donde se intenta colocar cada codigo de materia sin repeticion y que sume la cantidad cuando en tio de movimiwnto este la palabra entrada, al hacer wsta consulta hace una suma general de todos los materiales

Comment: Coloca las tablas que estas usando, no imágenes, código para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: tabla agregada.

Comment: En caso que no sea enrada? no suma?

Comment: correcto, solo quiero lograr la consulta que cuando diga entrada que sume la cantidad que entro del material

Comment: Gracias bro, y si quisiera que contara tambien las salidas fuera lo mismo?

Comment: Te edite le respuesta para que tengas una idea

Comment: probe el codigo bro pero al parecer suma todo, independiente sea ENTRADA o SALIDA

Comment: Verifica el ejemplo que te di https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/0 para que veas si algo te falto, use tu misma tabla tal cual como la colocaste

Comment: Igual si aun no te da coloca tu sql aca https://www.db-fiddle.com/ y me das el link para ayudarte mejor

Comment: en el ejemplo igual bro hace la sumatoria de todo independientemente si es salida o entrada.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ckNEQLqno6C61MirDPMff/0  (aqui va toda la db)

Comment: Claro pero eso quiere decir que no leiste mi respuesta, justo te coloque que es un ejemplo, ya con ello podias filtrar solos los registros ENTRADA, o como te fuese mas sencillo, si solo quieres los entrada no necesitas el **CASE** solo filtras **WHERE tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA'** y listo :)

Comment: pensé que era la consulta, entendí mal lo del ejemplo, muchas gracias bro me sirvio de mucho

Comment: Dale, recuerda si solo es los ENTRADA, no necesitas el CASE, puedes hacerlo con un WHERE sencillo y un SUM, te dejo la edicion en la respuesta

Comment: Disculpa amigo, pero si no logre filtrar cuando es salida o entrada siempre hace una sumatoria general, me podrias dar alguna pista de como seria

Comment: Revisaste el edit de mi respuesta? veo que no, asi que te dejo el query directamente **SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material, SUM(m.cantidad) as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m 
WHERE tipo_movimiento="ENTRADA";**

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor usar CASE de SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material,
CASE m.tipo_movimiento
    WHEN "ENTRADA" THEN (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE codigo_material=m.codigo_material)
    WHEN "SALIDA" THEN 0
END as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m;
```

Como ves, si es tipo "ENTRADA" realiza la suma de esas cantidades, si no da un 0, luego puedes filtrar que solo busque las entradas.

PD: te dejo un ejemplo Funcional con tu tabla:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/0

---

EDIT: Para poder sumar las salidas solo cambia el WHEN de SALIDA y te quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material,
CASE m.tipo_movimiento
    WHEN "ENTRADA" THEN (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE codigo_material=m.codigo_material)
    WHEN "SALIDA" THEN (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE codigo_material=m.codigo_material)
END as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m;
```

Luego puedes agregar más validaciones dentro del THEN ya queda de como lo necesites.

Claro si vas a sumar de igual manera entrada y salida no tiene caso el **CASE** y lo haces directamente con **SUM** y **DISTINCT**

---

EDIT 2:

Para solo filtrar los tipo **ENTRADA**

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.codigo_material, SUM(m.cantidad) as Cantidad
FROM movimientos m 
WHERE tipo_movimiento="ENTRADA";
```

Con eso lo puedes hacer sin necesidad del **CASE**